# Generic virtual method and concrete Implementation?

Tags: c#, generics

I'm currently working on a piece of code, where Generics are driving me crazy. Maybe somebody can point out the issue.

All our `DatabaseEntities` have common Interfaces, one for example is `IDatabaseEntityWithId`.

let's say there is `EntityA : IDatabaseEntityWithId`. We have different, non-generic Forms / Controls. We also have Controls that should be shared, and do their Job independent of the concrete Type.

Now, coming from Java this is quite easy there, cause every control could just use for example `List<?>` and pass / Process the list without actually caring what is inside.

So, our Search-Control should also be able to "deal" with `List<T>` and `IQueryable<T>` without caring what `T` actually is.

The base implementation for an `EntityList` has the following methods, which our Search should utilize to generate the results, do pagination, etc.

```
public class EntityListControl{
  public virtual IQueryable<T> BaseQuery<T>(DBContext dbContext) where T : IDBEntityWithId => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual List<string> AutocompleteSuggestionsQuickSearch() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual List<IDBEntityWithId> DoQuickSearch(string reference) => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual IQueryable<T> DoTaggedSearchExtensions<T>(IQueryable<T> query, DbContext dbContext) where T : IDBEntityWithId  => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The `SearchControl` has a reference to the currently loaded `EntityListControl` and basically should just act as orchestrator for the concrete methods, i.e. shortened it looks like:

```
class SearchControl{
   public void DoSearch(){
      String[] searchTags = this.SearchField.Text.Split(' ');
      using (DbContext db = DbContext.Factory()){
          var query = this.EntityListControl.BaseQuery<IDBEntityWithId>(db);
          
          //do other stuff.

          query = this.EntityListControl.DoTaggedSearchExtension<IDBEntityWithID>(query, db);
          
         //do other stuff

          List<IDBEntityWithId> result = query.Take(X).ToList();

         //do other stuff

          this.EntityListView.FactoryRows(result);
      }
```

You'll get the idea.

Now, for one of the `EntityListControl`-implementations, these methods might look like:

```
public class EntityList: UserControl{
    ...
}
...

public class EntityListA : EntityList{

   public override IQueryable<EntityA> BaseQuery<EntityA>(DbContext db){
       return db.EntityA.Include("EntityB").Include("EntityC");
   }

   public IQueryable<EntityA> DoTaggedSearchExtension<EntityA>(IQueryable<EntityA> query, DbContext db){
      //Problem is now here...
      return query.Where(x => x.PropertyOfEntityA == true);
   }
}
```

The Problem is now in the concrete implementation of `DoTaggedSearchExtension`. Visual Studio here clearly lines out, that `T` is `EntityA` and the query is `IQueryable<EntityA>` - but refuses to accept any properties that don't belong to `IDBEntityWithId`. Why is that?

The error Message even reads "EntityA does not contain a definition for 'property'...." - which is wrong, it is there... IntelliSense just proposes properties of the common interface.

Obviously in the generic `EntityListControl`, I can not be more concrete on the type of `T`, `IBaseEntityWithId` is one of the common interfaces I can ensure for all entities.

Ofc, I could leave away the whole generic-part and JUST work with interfaces, casting them to the actual type in the implementations, but that's not the point, isn't it?

Any suggestion on how to fix this particular example?

Answer (score 0):

You want the base class to be generic, not the methods!

```
public class EntityList<T> where T : IDBEntityWithId
{
  public virtual IQueryable<T> BaseQuery(DBContext dbContext) => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual List<string> AutocompleteSuggestionsQuickSearch() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual List<IDBEntityWithId> DoQuickSearch(string reference) => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public virtual IQueryable<T> DoTaggedSearchExtensions(IQueryable<T> query, DbContext dbContext) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

When you then implement this, you get the concrete types you expect

```
public class EntityListA : EntityList<EntityA>{

   public override IQueryable<EntityA> BaseQuery(DbContext db){
       return db.EntityA.Include("EntityB").Include("EntityC");
   }

   public IQueryable<EntityA> DoTaggedSearchExtension(IQueryable<EntityA> query, DbContext db){
      //Problem is now here... (Not any more it isnt!)
      return query.Where(x => x.PropertyOfEntityA == true);
   }
}
```

Live example for demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/SiICNV (Compiles fine but had to comment out the EF-specific stuff)

Comment: @dognose you're trying to make a search control that can work with ANY of your entities? I think therein lies the problem. How does a search control that deals with searching, say, Dogs also work for searching for star systems? Theyre completely different things

Comment: Deleted prior comment, read "SearchControl" first. Hmmm, that might work, but the Designer is not very good at handling Generic User Controls...

Comment: I still don't understand - nothing Ive put in this answer means you need to have a generic form control. In your question the `SearchControl` has a property which is the entity list. So you must have instantiated it somewhere.

Comment: The `specific` stuff is in the concrete methods. The generic search just handles stuff you do for EVERY search: Listing,  querying, limiting, paginating etc. Therefore it doesn't need to know, if it has to put 100 dogs or 100 star systems onto as many pages as the user setting allows ;)

Comment: Ok, so you might want to read up on the UnitOfWork, or repository pattern - this is done a lot but you need to distinguish the thing that loads/saves/etc data from the thing that displays it. Also look at patterns like MVC and MVVM

Comment: I think I have to pick that approach, with a "Non-Generic" class in between, to keep the Control working in Designer... `EntityListA : EntityListAStub` and `EntityListAStub : EntityList<EntityA>` (else the designer fails to render the control `EntityListA`, because it cannot construct the immediate parent through reflection when trying to show it in designer view) - and basically that's what I actually wanted to avoid for 2 Generic methods, so my though was "make these 2 methods generic, not the whole class".

Comment: Actually, It would compile, but won't work. `SearchControl` now has no way to hold a reference on `EntityList<T>`. While that could be defined, any usage / assignment now asks for the concrete Type of <T> - which is not known to SearchControl.

`EntityList<IDbEntityWithId> entityListReference = new EntityListA()` yields: Cannot implicitly conver type.... (also no explicit cast possible)

Answer (score 0):

The definition of DoTaggedSearchExtension identifies that T is a IDBEntityWithId

C# is strongly typed so it only allows methods defined on IDBEntityWithId

Comment: But what's the point then? If I need to know the concrete type everytime i want to use a generic class, how is that still eligible to be called generic?